# Interview Question: Maximum Profit by Investing in Stocks

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, greedy

Suppose we have M coins and we want to invest it in Stocks. There are **N** stocks in which he can invest some non-negative integer amount. The profit by stock **i** is given by a Quadratic function:

**A<sub>i</sub>X<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + B<sub>i</sub>X<sub>i</sub>**

where X<sub>i</sub> is an integer amount of money invested in stock **i**. **(−1000 ≤ A<sub>i</sub> ≤ −1) & (1 ≤ B<sub>i</sub> ≤ 1000)**

Design a Greedy Algorithm to find the maximum amount of money we can make?

It is not allowed to invest fractional amount of money in a stock. We can invest less than M coins.

Comment: Do you know what is greedy algorithm? Have you tried to implement it? Show your efforts.

Comment: @MBo I actually tried the case when the constraints are opposite i.e. (1<Ai<1000) & (-1000<Bi<-1). In this case, we either invest all of the money to one stocks or not invest at all. This way we have, profit = max(profit, stock[i].Ai * Xi^2 + stock[i].Bi * Yi^2) and it is giving correct results. I am not able to go with the case provided in above question. Please help!

Comment: The peak of that quadratic is at `x = -B / 2A`

Comment: @user3386109 Please elaborate. Yes, the Quadratic function will attain its extreme value at `X = -B/2A`. Should I sort the A and B values according to this in decreasing order and then invest coins in that order. Will it work then?

Comment: @ManavChhibber Please throw some light on this. Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the maximum valueof `M` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given function Y = A<sub>i</sub>X<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + B<sub>i</sub>X<sub>i</sub> is a quadratic function.
For the constraints, (−1000 ≤ Ai ≤ −1) and  (1 ≤ Bi ≤ 1000) investments can be represented as a parabolas as,

[image]
Notice three things :

1. These parabolas have their maximum at point given by  **X'<sub>i</sub> = -B<sub>i</sub> / 2A<sub>i</sub>**
2. We should always invest coins X<sub>i</sub> such that 0 ≤ X<sub>i</sub> ≤ X'<sub>i</sub> to yield a profit.
3. For a given number of coins k, it's better to invest them in the investment with larger maxima.

The greedy algorithm is then,

1. Iterate over all N investments and for each i find it's corresponding **X<sub>i</sub> = floor(X'<sub>i</sub>).**
2. Take the all such k investments greedily(investment with maximum X<sub>i</sub> first) such that **Sum(X<sub>i</sub>) ≤ M** for all such i taken.

Here's pseudocode to get you started,

```
FIND_MAX(A, B, N, M):
    allProfits = [[]]
    for i = 1 to N:
        profit = []
        X = floor((-B[i]) / (2 * A[i]))
        profit.coins = X
        profit.index = i
        allProfits[i] =  profit
    Sort(allProfits)
    maxProfit = 0
    for j = N downto 1:
        if(M <= 0):
            break
        coins = min(allProfits[j].coins, M)
        i = allProfits[j].index
        maxProfit += (A[i] * coins * coins) + (B[i] * coins)
        M -= coins
    return maxProfit
```

Comment: If X_i is not an integer you need to `round(X_i)`

Comment: @user3386109 yes that's why I'm taking `floor(X'i)`

Comment: @ManavChhibber Shouldn't X = floor((-B[i]) / (2 * A[i]))?

Comment: @ManavChhibber 
`A1 = 2, B1 = 3
 A2 = -1,B2 = 5
 A3 = -2,B3 = 10

M = 3`

Then, we should get 16 as optimal solution but in this case it only returns 12.

Comment: @NadirAli yeah seems like rather always looking for maximum coins we should take as much we can. Modifying the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A greedy algorithm provides the best solution indeed in such a case.

The point is that, if for a given stock `x` coins have already be invested, then the expected gain for the next spent is equal to:

```
next_gain = f(x+1) - f(x) = 2ax + a + b
```

As `a` is negative, this gain is always decreasing with `x`, the number of coins already invested. To be pedantic, the gain function is concave.

Then it can be easily proved that the optimal solution is obtained by spending the coins one by one, looking for the stock with the maximum `next_gain`. This can be implemented with a `max_heap`, leading to a complexity `O(M logN)`.

If `M`is very large, then other solutions should be foreseen, for example based on a Lagrangian function. More maths would be involved in this case. As you mentioned that you are looking to a greedy solution, I supposed this greedy solution is fast enough.

Here is the code in C++. Should be easy to translate to any code having a max-heap.

Output:

```
Profit = 16
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

struct Stock {
    int index;
    int n_bought;
    int next_gain;
    Stock (int i, int n, int gain) : index(i), n_bought(n), next_gain (gain) {};
    friend operator< (const Stock& x, const Stock& y) {return x.next_gain < y.next_gain;};
};

long long int profit (std::vector<int>& A, std::vector<int>& B, int M) {
    int n = A.size();
    if (n != B.size()) exit (1);
    std::priority_queue<Stock> candidates;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int gain = A[i] + B[i];
        if (gain > 0) candidates.emplace(Stock(i, 0, gain));
    }
    long long int sum = 0.0;
    int coins = 0;
    while ((coins < M) &&(!candidates.empty())) {
        auto zebest = candidates.top();
        candidates.pop();
        coins++;
        sum += zebest.next_gain;
        zebest.n_bought++;
        int i = zebest.index;
        int gain = 2*A[i]*zebest.n_bought + A[i] + B[i];
        if (gain > 0) {
            zebest.next_gain = gain;
            candidates.push (zebest);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A = {-2, -1, -2};
    std::vector<int> B = {3, 5, 10};
    int M = 3;

    auto ans = profit (A, B, M);
    std::cout << "Profit = " << ans << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```